# ExtJs5 -Ext.tab.Panel with Ext.panel.Panel containing CodeMirror - TypeError: ownerContext.overflowContext is null

Tags: javascript, extjs, typeerror, codemirror

The code in the end of this post throws an error (visible in **Firebug**):

```
TypeError: ownerContext.overflowContext is null
return ownerContext.overflowXStyle || (ownerContext.overflowXStyle = this.owner....
ext-all-debug.js (row 75928, column 8)
```

**Basically what the code does in words is:**

- create two Ext.panel.Panel (**panel_1**, **panel_2**) and one Ext.tab.Panel (**tab_panel**)
- add **panel_1** and **panel_2** to **tab_panel** *items*
- add **tab_panel** to *Ext.Viewport* (**vp**)
- create a [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#api_constructor) object (**code_mirror_editor**) using a *callback-function* (**code_mirror_callback_function**) , which replaces the standart-ExtJS-content of panel_1 with the CodeMirror object

I am using [ExtJs 5.1](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api) with [CodeMirror 5.3](http://codemirror.net/index.html):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- ext imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/ext-5.1.1/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script>

    <!-- codemirror imports -->
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/CodeMirror-master/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/CodeMirror-master/lib/codemirror.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/CodeMirror-master/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function(){
            var    panel_1    = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    frame:true,
                    title: 'panel_1'
            });

            var panel_2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                frame:true,
                title: 'panel_2',
                html: "some-html"
            });

            var tab_panel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
                frame:true,
                title: 'tab_panel',
                items:[panel_1,panel_2]
            });

            var vp = new Ext.Viewport({
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [tab_panel],
                renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });

            var code_mirror_callback_function = function(codeMirrorEl) {
                var panel_1_dom = panel_1.el.dom;
                panel_1_dom.replaceChild(codeMirrorEl, panel_1_dom.childNodes[0]);
            };

            var code_mirror_editor = CodeMirror(code_mirror_callback_function, {
                lineWrapping: true,
                lineNumbers: true,
                value: "<XXX><YYY><AAA>foo1</AAA></YYY><ZZZ>foo2</ZZZ></XXX>"
            });
            code_mirror_editor.setSize(500,250);
            code_mirror_editor.refresh();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
```

**Now here comes the problem:**
You can switch for approximately 30 seconds between the tabs and everything works fine (The time-interval may vary). After some time-interval though the aforementioned **TypeError** occurs, after switching again to **panel_1**.

***What can i do to circumvent this error?***

---

---

I have already tried the following:

- instead of using a callback-function, i call 
  `var code_mirror_editor = CodeMirror(panel_1.body, {
      lineWrapping: true,
      lineNumbers: true,
      value: "<XXX><YYY><AAA>foo1</AAA></YYY><ZZZ>foo2</ZZZ></XXX>"
  });` and in `panel_1`set `autoScroll: true`
  Result: The error is gone, but i have a huge unfilled div which leaves a big blank space inside **panel_1**. So the result is no solution.
- Run my code in [Sencha-Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/omq):
  Result: The error **does also occur** on Sencha-Fiddle.
- **Observation**: The Error solely appears in ExtJs 5.1. In ExtJs 5.0 the error **does not** happen.

Comment: I do not see any errors - http://jsfiddle.net/t254uzcm/(chrome&safari)

Comment: That is probably because you dont load any css files in the HTML.

Comment: for example http://jsfiddle.net/t254uzcm/1/

Comment: I am using Extjs5. Could not find it in the Version combobox of fiddle though...

Comment: uff, look at this https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/omq

Comment: Ok, in fiddle and jsfiddle it may cause no errors, but on my `localhost` web server it does. Thanks for your fiddle examples though. It makes the error even more awkward and annoying.

Comment: Actually the error DOES occur in Sencha-Fiddle with ExtJs5.1. Why does this error occur?